# How to add Sub-Reports in Multi-Page SRSS Reports?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

We are using SQL Server Reporting Services for our reports.  We have a report that is comprised of several sub reports.  For simplicity, let's say cars.  And each car has it's own part list.  A one-to-many relationship.

So on the Car report, there's all the car information - and a sub-report, the part list.  This works fine for a single car as there is a single Car.ID, which can be passed as a parameter to filter the Part List by the specific car.

But, if there's several cars specified to the report, we want each car to be on it's own page.  with it's own part list.

I've had a look around an am struggling to figure it out.  The solution I'm looking at involves putting everything in a List control, adding a page break after each record.  Then adding a row number to each item in the dataset, then matching page number and the row number up for the sub-report.

I figure there's got to be a simpler way  to do this, that I've overlooked.  Or if there isn't, how can I match up the Page Number and Row Number?  I've tried using the Lookup function --

```
=Lookup(=Fields!Page.Value, =Globals!PageNumber, =Fields!ID.Value, "DataSet1")
```

However, this returns an error that the Globals!PageNumber variable is only available to the page header/footer sections.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind, I was being an idiot and completely over complicating it.

If anyone else find it useful, here's the steps.

1. Create your sub-reports, specifying the ID of the record as a parameter.
2. Create your main, encapsulating report.
3. Add a list control to the page, go to the Tablix properties and add a page break.
4. Add your sub-reports to the list control
5. Specify the value to the identity parameter, by using the fields collection - in this case:
   =Fields!ID.Value
6. Test report, then sit back and don't think about how complicated I tried to make it.